# Wrong normals when blender export object file to WebGL

Tags: webgl, blender

I have an object created using blender and I set all the normal correctly using `ctrl`+`n`. I'm sure that all the normals are set correctly in blender. However when I export the object to .obj format with 'write normal' option and export to WebGL, half of my mesh are disappear, seems like the normals are export incorrectly.

The mesh that disappear are using mirror modifier and LoopTools-bridge to generate.

When I disable the 'write normal' option, the object display correctly but I cannot put lights on the object.

What is the possible problem, which step I miss when I export the file from blender?

[image]

It should be a sphere like object but it lost half of the mesh

Answer (score 0):

> I just found that WebGL only support 16bit vertex buffer, if my object
>   include normals. I have to downsample my vertex number to 16bit/3. And
>   the problem fixed.

---

Edit-

I fix this problem by reduce my vertex number

Comment: WebGL supports 32bit vertex buffers just fine. Maybe you meant 16bit index buffers? Although pretty much all GPUs support 32bit index buffers as well by enabling [`OES_element_index_uint`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/) which according to [webglstats.com](http://webglstats.com) includes > 97% of all devices. The limit is in whatever library you're using not WebGL. You should edit your question to show which library your using because this is not a WebGL issue. It's an issue with your library.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to WebGL. I don't know which library cause this error, the only library import to my project is webgl-obj-loader.js (this library help me to import .obj to my project). Is this the issue cause my problem?

Comment: If you're referring to this [webgl-obj-loader](https://github.com/frenchtoast747/webgl-obj-loader), then it uses 32bit int arrays for VBO information and 16 bit for the array element indices.